# Elements do not expand to contain child content

Tags: html, css, height

I am building a forum and therefore I am building a preview of a new post. 
It is also for the layout of each post on my forum. When I added some text to my paragraph it becomes longer the more I add, but that's not my problem like I asked before.

My problem is as you can see in the code below (full page view) that the container does not grow by adding text to my paragraph. I just put in some dummy text so that you can see what my problem is.

```css
#prevContainer {
    width:95%;
    background-color:white;
    opacity:1;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height:150px;
    height:auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border:2px solid grey;
}
#prevContainer #left {
    border-right:2px solid grey;
    width: 120px;
    min-height:150px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
#prevContainer #left #prevAvatar {
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
#prevContainer #right {
    float:left;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    min-height: 150px;
    height:auto;
    min-width:200px;
    width:500px;
    max-width: 517px;
}
#prevContainer #right #text {
    margin-left:10px;
}
#prevContainer #right #text #prevOutput {
    background-color:yellow;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: break-all;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="prevContainer">
                                <div id="left">
                                    <img id="prevAvatar" src="" alt="Avatar"/>
                                </div>
                                <div id="right">
                                    <div id="text">
                                        <p id="prevOutput">
                                        I HOPE THIS WORKS I HOPE THIS WORKS
                                        I HOPE THIS WORKS I HOPE THIS WORKS
                                        I HOPE THIS WORKS I HOPE THIS WORKS 
                                        I HOPE THIS WORKS I HOPE THIS WORKS
                                        I HOPE THIS WORKS I HOPE THIS WORKS
                                        I HOPE THIS WORKS I HOPE THIS WORKS
                                        I HOPE THIS WORKS I HOPE THIS WORKS
                                        I HOPE THIS WORKS I HOPE THIS WORKS
                                        I HOPE THIS WORKS I HOPE THIS WORKS
                                        I HOPE THIS WORKS I HOPE THIS WORKS
                                        I HOPE THIS WORKS I HOPE THIS WORKS
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--<button id="button">New Post</button>-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see the problem. The yellow element contains the text.

Comment: it is growing with text , there isnt any problem

Comment: The problem can be seen in "Full Page" view. It's not about the yellow paragraph but the one that holds it.

Comment: maybe not at a small size but if you set your screen size at 1080p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not clearing the floats. You can add `overflow: hidden;` to `#prevContainer` or use:

```
#prevContainer:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. It works, but as you can see the other elements don't grow with the text, do you have an solution for this too?

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden` to the element in each troublesome scenario.

Comment: Remove `border-right` from the `#left` div, add the same `border-left` to the `#right` div :)

Comment: thanks. but that does not work for my #left div. Although, my border-right property doesn't become any longer :(

Comment: @KaloyanIvanov that's a very easy solution indeed. It works fine now, thank you for your help. Could you please describe why your solution makes the difference?

Comment: Regarding floats: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html , regarding borders: the right div in your case is always higher than the left one so adding the border to it makes sure that border will always reach the bottom of the wrapper. Using the browser's inspect element function will make it clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Add top and bottom padding to the containers that the text goes in.

Comment: That approach doesn't add dynamic sizing.